# Euler characteristic of a Vector bundle vanishes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

It seems that I have proven something wierd, namely that the Euler Characteristic of every vector bundle vanishes:

Every vector bundle has a non-trivial involution ($(p,u)\rightarrow (p,-v)$) and therefore is the boundary of another manifold. Using that bounding manifolds have Euler characteristic $0$ we get that every Vector bundle must also.

First of all, is the proof correct? And if it is, can anybody give any intuition behind it? While I have proved it , it seems very odd to me. For example which manifold does the Mobious Strip bound ?

Comment: So, $\mathbb{R}$ is (the total space of) a trivial vector bundle over a point. It has a nontrivial involution, but its Euler characteristic is $1$. More generally, (the total space of) a vector bundle over a space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$, so has the same Euler characteristic as $X$. It sounds like you might be invoking facts that only apply to compact manifolds?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Of course you are right. One thing that *certainly* is wrong is what I have written about the involution: It must also be without fixed points , which the one I have exhibited obviously isn't.

Comment: Let me furthermore add that a compact manifold that bounds a compact manifold with boundary has to have even Euler characteristic, not vanishing Euler characteristic. (Consider $S^2$, which certainly bounds $D^3$ but has Euler characteristic 2)